# Tips for Project Euler Problem #78

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This is the problem in question: [Problem #78](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=78)

This is driving me crazy. I've been working on this for a few hours now and I've been able to reduce the complexity of finding the number of ways to stack `n` coins to `O(n/2)`, but even with those improvements *and* starting from an `n` for which `p(n)` is close to one-million, I still can't reach the answer in under a minute. Not at all, actually.

Are there any hints that could help me with this?

Keep in mind that I don't want a full solution and there shouldn't be any functional solutions posted here, so as not to spoil the problem for other people. This is why I haven't included any code either.

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to solve in a less than a minute?

Comment: That's sort of the rule of thumb at Project Euler. Bluntly put: If the algorithm can't solve it in under a minute, it sucks, and is therefore not a good solution. I want a good solution.

Comment: I can't give you any specific advice, but I posted some general advice a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537306/recommended-reading-for-solving-project-euler-problems/1537531#1537531

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) can help you here. I assume that the solution you already have is a recursion such as the one in the section "intermediate function". This can be used to find the solution to the Euler problem, but isn't fast.

A much better way is to use the recursion based on the [pentagonal number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) in the next section. The proof of this theorem isn't straight forward, so I don't think the authors of the problem expect that you come up with the theorem by yourself. Rather it is one of the problems, where they expect some literature search.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is really asking to find the first term in the sequence of integer partitions that’s divisible by 1,000,000.

A partition of an integer, n, is one way of describing how many ways the sum of positive integers, ≤ n, can be added together to equal n, regardless of order. The function p(n) is used to denote the number of partitions for n. Below we show our 5 “coins” as addends to evaluate 7 partitions, that is p(5)=7.

5 = 5
= 4+1
= 3+2
= 3+1+1
= 2+2+1
= 2+1+1+1
= 1+1+1+1+1

We use a generating function to create the series until we find the required n.
The generating function requires at most 500 so-called generalized pentagonal numbers, given by n(3n – 1)/2 with 0, ± 1, ± 2, ± 3…, the first few of which are 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 15, 22, 26, 35, … (Sloane’s A001318).

We have the following generating function which uses our pentagonal numbers as exponents:

1 - q - q^2 + q^5 + q^7 - q^12 - q^15 + q^22 + q^26 + ...

my blog at blog.dreamshire.com has a perl program that solves this in under 10 sec.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done problems [31](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=31) or [76](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=76) yet?  They form a nice set that is an generalization of the same base problem each time.  Doing the easier questions may give you insight into a solution for 78.

Comment: sadly, divisible by 1000000 is way too big. I cannot solve it using the solution to problem 76

Answer (score 0):

here some hints:

1. Divisibility by one million is not the same thing as just being larger than one million. 1 million = 1,000,000 = 10^6 = 2^6 * 5^6.
2. So the question is to find a lowest n so that the factors of p(n) contain six 2's and six 5's.

Comment: Are you sure about (2.)? This would be a reasonable (or even the best) approach if (2) were true, but AFAIK there is no multiplicative identity for p(n): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29